# Joining dictionary terms to form string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

So, I have a dictionary of terms where each key is a word from a text file, and the value is a list of the next two words in that text file.

```
def dict(txt, n):
    txt = txt.split()
    output = {}
    for i in range(len(txt)-n+1):
        t = ' '.join(txt[i:i+1])
        p = text[i+1:i+n]
        output.setdefault(t, 0)
        output[t] = p
    return output
```

The output is a dictionary of things like:

```
{'had':['a','little'], 'Mary':['had','a'], 'a': ['little', 'lamb.']}
```

(Mine is actually much longer, as it is analyzing a long paper.)

My question is, how do I join these terms back together by reading the key, and then printing the values, then reading the last value and then finding a key that matches that value. The goal is ultimately to get a randomized paragraph, provided using a large document.

So far, I have something along the lines of:

```
if output[t] == text[1]:
    return output
    print(output.join(' ')
```

But this isn't returning anything. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused.  Given the output dictionary that you posted as an example, can you post what the ultimate output that you want is?  is it `"Mary had a little lamb"`?

Comment: Or, "lamb had mary a little"? (shuffled)

Comment: It seems like a dictionary is the wrong structure here because keys are unique. What do you plan to do when there are multiple `a`s in your text, each with different phrases following them?

Comment: And you don't seem to have tried much. You should do some research before posting (in general).

Comment: If you want a random paragraph, why not just `random.shuffle` the words in the paragraph and be done with it?

Comment: Don't make a variable named `dict` because it hides the builtin `dict` data-type.

Comment: To those confused why I'm not using a shuffle function: My teacher wants a string of words drawn from the original paper to create a shorter randomized paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `join` does not work like you expect, perhaps.

You are thinking that you write

```
collection.join(join_character)
```

but it is

```
join_character.join(collection)
```

You should expect to write code like

```
' '.join(output)
```

What exactly you need for `output` is up to you; I expect you can figure that part out.  It just looks like you were using `join` incorrectly here.

Answer (score 0):

This will add terms until `dic` does not contain `key`.

```
dic = {'had': ['a', 'little'], 'Mary': ['had', 'a'], 'a': ['little', 'lamb.']}
key = 'Mary'
res = []

while True:
    try:
        res.extend(dic[key])
        key = dic[key][-1]
    except KeyError:
        break

print ' '.join(res)
```

This yields:

```
['had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb.']
```

Be aware: You will enter an infinite loop if all values also are a key. You will also encounter this if there is a repeating sequence in your dictionary, such as

```
{'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'c'], 'c': ['a', 'b'], 'foo': ['bar', 'foobar']}
```

To avoid this, you could do one out of two things:

1. Set a maximum iteration value
2. Stop the iteration when you encounter a key that previously have been seen.

**Maximum iteration value:**

```
dic = {'had': ['a', 'little'], 'Mary': ['had', 'a'], 'a': ['little', 'lamb.']}
key = 'Mary'
res = []
max_iterations = 10
i = 0

while i < max_iterations
    try:
        res.extend(dic[key])
        key = dic[key][-1]
    except KeyError:
        break
    i += 1
    if i > max_iterations:
        break
print ' '.join(res)
```

**Stop at previously seen key**

```
dic = {'had': ['a', 'little'], 'Mary': ['had', 'a'], 'a': ['little', 'lamb.']}
key = 'Mary'
res = []
seen_keys = []

while True:
    if key in seen_keys:
        break
    try:
        res.extend(dic[key])
        seen_keys.append(key)
        key = dic[key][-1]
    except KeyError:
        break

print ' '.join(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a bunch. I still have to join all the words from res into a string, but I can manage that on my own I believe. :)

Comment: @user3063539 I updated my answer. To join a sequence of strings, the prefered method is to use `join()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure `dict['word1'] = ('word2', 'word3')` requires you to search into the data values, which is very inefficient.

It would be much easier to look up if it was organized as `dict[('word1', 'word2')] = ['possible', 'word3', 'values']`.

```
from itertools import tee, izip
from collections import defaultdict
from random import choice

def triwise(iterable):
    a,b,c = tee(iter(iterable), 3)
    next(b, None)
    next(c, None)
    next(c, None)
    return izip(a, b, c)

def make_lookup(txt):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    words = ['', ''] + txt.strip().split() + ['', '']
    for w1, w2, w3 in triwise(words):
        res[(w1, w2)].append(w3)
    return dict(res)

def make_sentence(lookup):
    w1, w2 = '', ''
    words = []
    while True:
        w1, w2 = w2, choice(lookup[(w1, w2)])
        if w2 == '':
            return ' '.join(words)
        else:
            words.append(w2)

def main():
    txt = 'Mary had a little lamb whose fleece was white as snow'
    lookup = make_lookup(txt)
    print(make_sentence(lookup))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```